# How do you stop users directly accessing files on a website in IIS 7

Tags: security, iis

I have a website where users upload files through a CMS.

eg http://www.mysite.com/uploadedfiles/file1.txt

I want to stop users on the internet being able to enter this URL into a browser and access these files directly.
How can I do this?

I still need to allow IIS to read, modify and delete these files through the CMS though.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend either saving the files to a non-web-accessible directory, or creating a random name before saving to disk.

Comment: Agreed.  Save them to c:\uploads or something similar which is accessible by the application but not directly through the site.

Answer (score 1):

How about configuring the site to accept connections only from the ip address of the CMS?

Comment: Can I do that only for a particular directory and its sub directories? Also, where do I do this in IIS from the image above?

Comment: You should be able to. Do it from the IPv4 and Domain Restrictions component.

Comment: "IP address and domain Restrictions" is the setting you're looking for. It is set per directory and is inherited, by default, by all the sub-directories and files contained.

Answer (score 1):

Go in "request filtering" and disallow the specific URL (in the "URL" tab).

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this secure, you'll have to implement it in your application in a different way.

Save the uploaded files in a folder that isn't accessible through a web request, for example in a external folder `D:\WebData\MyApp\Uploads`. Make sure that the Network Service account has "modify" access on this directory (for your CMS app).

Then, implement a [HTTP handler in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) that checks the Session of the CMS user and allow them to only download/modify/access their own files.

Answer (score -2):

go to Authorization Rules then add a Deny Rule for all users on the desired folder.